# Concatenate multiple rows of Column B until column A contains X then, loop again

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWTOB.png)

I need to do this in excel and I do know how to do this with python etc, but it has to be done in excel either VBA or formula (best option).

Column A, contains a "W" character. 
Column B, contains a "abc" cell that will be the same everywhere (The other rows won't be the same).
Column C, I am concatenating all cells in column B before column A hits a "W" value.

I want to achieve some sort of a formula in a single or multiple steps that will allow me to concatenate all B column rows until column A has a "W". The concatenation must happen in same row as "abc" in column B, but paste on column C.

Thank you in advance

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use column D (as an intermediate step) as well as C, set C2 to

```
=IF(A2="W",D2,"")
```

and set D2 to

```
=B2&IF(A3="W","",";;"&D3)
```

then copy column C and D down as far as necessary.